# How can the universe be flat?

Tags: cosmological-inflation

In each video I see on Alan Guth or anyone explaining cosmic inflation and how it solved the flatness problem, it is said that "the repulsive effect of gravity thus change how omega evolves and thus drives it exponentially toward 1", be it an MIT lecture or an interview.
How does changing the way omega evolves drive it to 1? Like where is the math or intuition?
(i know what omega is)

Comment: You have mentioned videos on Alan Guth and others, also MIT lectures and interviews.  And you have made a direct quote.   I assume that the quote is from a particular video, or interview, or lecture.  Please tell us exactly the source of the quote.

Comment: This is most important, because we can repeat the same stuff that is in the videos, lectures and interviews. And that would be pointless to you.  For example, I could repeat what is in this paper... https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0101507.pdf  but if you've already watched 5 videos that summarises the same ideas as this paper, that would be pointless.